# Txpool not receiving any new pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, pending-transactions, txpool

This seems to happen randomly during an influx of new transactions. I am running a node with high txpool limits.

`--txpool.globalslots 1000000 --txpool.accountslots 128 --txpool.accountqueue 512 --txpool.globalqueue 500000`

Calling txpool.status
`{ pending: 144598, queued: 7244 }`

5 mins later: `{ pending: 144598, queued: 7747 }`

The pending number is not increasing, while transactions are still being added to queued.

While this is happening, I am receiving no new transactions from the following web3 subscription.

```
web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
})
.on("data", function(transaction){
    console.log(transaction);
    let promise = web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction);
    promise.then((data) => {
        if(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Everything will return to normal after a period of time (>15 mins).

Memory usage is normal and stable, CPU usage is a bit higher than normal, but not maxed out.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the pending transactions number is relating to all network transactions. It takes a time to propagate new transactions from your local node queue. It may also depend on the Gas fee, so underpaid transactions might be rejected from the limited queues of other nodes